# Why is the path parabolic in a central force field if the energy is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

In Section 15 of Landau and Lifshitz Classical Mechanics, they discuss the path of a particle under a central field. They show that the path is a conic with a focus at the origin. When the energy of the system is 0, the say the path is a parabola. Here they say, "This case occurs if the particle starts from rest at infinity." If a particle started from rest wouldn't it go directly to the center of the central force, i.e., the focus which is the origin? That doesn't lie on the parabola that the theory says the path follows.

Comment: I don't know exactly the derivation but I do know that for a central force like gravity, and a mass is in an parabolic trajectory, around a celestial body, then it has total energy equal to zero.  https://oer.pressbooks.pub/lynnanegeorge/chapter/chapter-2-orbit-geometry/

Comment: Talking about infinity definitely doesn't help intuitive understanding of the problem. Would it be easier to understand if it said "as the time approaches ±infinity, the velocity _assumptotically_ approaches zero"? If not, the only thing left to do is to go through the maths...

Comment: @user1079505 So it would be the case that if the particle started out at rest finite distance away (however large), it would first just go straight to the center, but if it starts out at rest an infinite distance away it follows a parabola?

Comment: Infinite time and distance aren't well-defined conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow a parabolic orbit, a particle has to have zero total energy but a non-zero amount of angular momentum. It is this latter requirement that keeps it from being able to get to the origin, since a particle can only get to $r=0$ if it has $l = 0$.

In the limit as $r\to\infty$, such a particle must have $v\to 0$ (since it has zero total energy.) However, the angular momentum can still remain non-zero in this limit since $\vec{l} = m \vec{r} \times \vec{v}$, whose magnitude is indeterminate in the limit as $|\vec{r}|\to \infty$.

Comment: I guess I assumed 'at rest' would be mean zero angular momentum also. This explanation makes perfect sense, though I'm disappointed the authors are so cryptic.